# Error parsing date string

Tags: java, date-parsing

I need to parse this string as a date:

> Mon Jun 10 00:00:00 CEST 2013

Here is what I do:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ccc MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

But I get a `ParseException`:

```
Unparseable date: "Wed Oct 02 00:00:00 CEST 2013" (at offset 0)
```

Any help please?

Comment: Where does `ccc` come from? I suspect you want `EEE`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Probably it's a typo, using `ccc` would have fired a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'`

Comment: Oh, and you probably want to specify Locale.US (or something similar) - otherwise it'll be using your system default locale...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have said, you need `EEE` instead of `ccc` - but you should *also* specify a locale, so that it doesn't try to parse the month and day names (and other things) using your system default locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy",
                                            Locale.US);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your format is wrong. You need to use `EEE` instead of `ccc`, where `E` means `Day name in week`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) regarding all the valid patterns available for `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I get the same exception :(

Comment: I'm sure it was a typo, as it would have fired `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'` instead of a `ParseException`

Comment: @DanieleVitali - [Working example](http://ideone.com/XAYwJ4). Are you sure you're using the exact same format?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `ccc` with `EEE` in the pattern to specify the day of the week:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

**Example:** https://gist.github.com/kmb385/8781482

Comment: I get the same exception :(

Comment: I'm sure it was a typo, as it would have fired `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'c'` instead of a `ParseException`

Comment: @DanieleVitali Checkout this gist: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/8781482 Also could you post the full code for your example?

Answer (score 1):

Update the format as below :

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a `Locale` problem. That's because dates are represented differently between `Locale`s, so the JVM fires an exception if the `Date` is not in the correct format. You can solve it by setting a custom Locale:

```
String str = "Mon Jun 10 00:00:00 EST 2013";
Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date = sdf.parse(str);
System.out.println(date);
```

IDEone examples do work because the default locale is `Locale.US`

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21524742/10819573) uses `SimpleDateFormat` which was the correct thing to do in Feb 2014. In Mar 2014, the `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` were supplanted by the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html). Since then, it is highly recommended to stop using the legacy date-time API.

**Note**: [Never use date-time formatting/parsing API without a `Locale`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

**Solution using the modern date-time API**:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String stdDateTime = "Mon Jun 10 00:00:00 CEST 2013";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(stdDateTime, parser);
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2013-06-10T00:00+02:00[Europe/Paris]
```

If for any reason, you need an instance of `java.util.Date`, you can get it as follow:

```
Date date = Date.from(zdt.toInstant());
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/wBeEn6)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.